# Import Node and Edge csv file structure for Gephi

Tags: csv, gephi

Can anyone tell me how to structure The Import node and a edge csv file to create a network graph in Gephi using the downloaded csv file from LinkedIn, I have goggled this question but can find very little.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you actually have the downloaded csv from linkedIn or is that part of your question?

In I think, if you do

```
File > Open... > CSV Files
```

Then all you can do is have a list of edges like this:

```
"A","B"
"B","C"
"C","D"
```

If instead you go to the Data Laboratory, then you can do import spreadsheet as a "Nodes Table" or an "Edges Table". The edges table csv file looks like this:

```
Source,Target,Type,Id,Label,Weight
145,147,Directed,465,,1.0
145,150,Directed,466,,1.0
145,159,Directed,467,,1.0
146,156,Directed,468,,1.0
```

<del>There is a labs tool that LinkedIn provides here http://inmaps.linkedinlabs.com/ that draws a nice network graph.</del> UPDATE - LinkedIn no longer offers this tool.